# Cannot push django app to Heroku

Tags: django, git, heroku

I am trying to deploy a CMS application on Heroku. But when I try

```
git push heroku master
```

I am getting the following errors.

```
Counting objects: 2841, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2775/2775), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2841/2841), 13.35 MiB | 497.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 2841 (delta 917), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.6.6
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_2e9a3f2d21d5a1b3c5ab348811182510/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_2e9a3f2d21d5a1b3c5ab348811182510/requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
remote:        No matching distribution found for pkg-resources==0.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_2e9a3f2d21d5a1b3c5ab348811182510/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to peaceful-olympic-84671.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/peaceful-olympic-84671.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/peaceful-olympic-84671.git'
```

I have already seen many answers to this same question on stack overflow but none of the answers is working for me. Please help.

Update: Removing the `pkg-resources` from `requirements.txt` helped. But the application isn't being displayed. It says application errors, check your logs for details.

[image: 1]]

This is my log file in Heroku.

```
2018-07-04T13:19:20.003057+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn zoomtail.wsgi --log-file -`
2018-07-04T13:19:22.351320+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-07-04T13:19:22.264506+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2018-07-04T13:19:22.329998+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2018-07-04T15:49:08.058951+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=peaceful-olympic-84671.herokuapp.com request_id=b22e6349-7456-4bfe-bb40-7be7b285e027 fwd="106.206.63.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-04T15:49:08.609553+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=peaceful-olympic-84671.herokuapp.com request_id=cb458cf7-fd71-4342-a3be-e46f258b6072 fwd="106.206.63.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-04T15:49:44.078076+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=peaceful-olympic-84671.herokuapp.com request_id=a3d03045-0204-44e4-9739-afeaa95eb1d0 fwd="106.206.63.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-04T15:49:45.057346+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=peaceful-olympic-84671.herokuapp.com request_id=dde12264-b1a6-4394-8427-4f431a292a6c fwd="106.206.63.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-04T15:52:41.870237+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=peaceful-olympic-84671.herokuapp.com request_id=95caff68-1fc2-4767-a835-e3e51fb867a8 fwd="106.206.63.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-04T15:52:42.608603+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=peaceful-olympic-84671.herokuapp.com request_id=7b5ad55a-8c59-4c92-8480-a9ed11572306 fwd="106.206.63.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I cannot make sense of the error. Please help.

Comment: what does your log file in heroku say

Comment: What is a log file in Heroku?

Comment: go on heroku.com. login and go to your app. at the top right, click on "more" then "view logs"

Comment: This is my log file in Heroku. I have edited the question and added it.

Comment: It says `gunicorn command not found`. Did you include `gunicorn` in your `requirements.txt` file

Comment: I have gunicorn in my requirements.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Following line from `requirements.txt` before push to heroku.

```
pkg-resources==0.0.0
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. I have updated the question. Please help.