# Heroku deployed django site giving application error

Tags: python, django, heroku, gunicorn

I am trying to deploy a Django application on Heroku. The deployment and push the changes is successful. But when opened it is giving application error, check your logs for details.

This is the log details on my terminal.

[image: 1]]

This is log details on Heroku.

```
2018-07-04T17:21:45.827547+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2018-07-04T17:21:51.960062+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn zoomtail.wsgi --log-file -`
2018-07-04T17:21:53.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-07-04T17:21:53.804826+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2018-07-04T17:21:53.758720+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2018-07-04T17:21:53.822387+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-07-04T17:22:39.313982+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=peaceful-olympic-84671.herokuapp.com request_id=2f38b8b0-9220-4f00-baa9-df9d2f1c54f7 fwd="106.206.63.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-07-04T17:22:40.055033+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=peaceful-olympic-84671.herokuapp.com request_id=3e5fb340-96f6-44c7-ad0a-3be4815fa5dc fwd="106.206.63.203" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I'm guessing the problem is with gunicorn since it says bash: gunicorn command not found. But I have installed it, added it in Procfile and requirements.txt, tried out the methods in similar stackoverflow questions but to no avail. Please help.

Comment: Can you run this & see what happens! ```heroku run pip install gunicorn```

Comment: I did this but it didn't take out the error. But I according to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51169401/cannot-push-django-app-to-heroku/51169459#51169459 The issue is now resolved. Thanks.